# How to quickly migrate from one table into another one with different table structure in the same/different cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I had one table with more than 10,000,000 records in Cassandra, but for some reason, I want to build another Cassandra table with the same fields and several additional fields, and I will migrate the previous data into it. And now the two tables are in the same Cassandra cluster.

I want to ask how to finish this task in a shortest time?

And If my new table in the different Cassandra, How to do it?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: what are these additional fields (any one primary or clustering keys) ? Where will you get data for this.  Using COPY command to export the data to new file, add additional data and then COPY to the new table.

Comment: these additional fields are general other than primary or clustering keys, the data are stored in the Cassandra. And now, the additional fields are blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to add blank fields to a table, then the best thing to do is use the `alter table` command to add the fields to the existing table.  Then no copying of the data would be needed and the new fields would show up as `null` in the existing rows until you set them to something.

If you want to change the structure of the data in the new table, or write it to a different cluster, then you'd probably need to write an application to read each row of the old table, transform the data as needed, and then write each row to the new location.

You could also do this by exporting the data to a csv file, write a program to restructure the csv file as needed, then import the csv file into the new location.

Another possible method would be to use Apache Spark.  You'd read the existing table into an RDD, transform and filter the data into a new RDD, then save the transformed RDD to the new table.  That would only work within the same cluster and would be fairly complex to set up.